# Check source for links with max characters using regex

Tags: regex

using `/<a [^>]*\bhref\s*=\s*"\K[^"]*anyurl.com[^"]*/`helps me scraping the urls I am looking for. But I would like to get urls only, which are not longer than 20 characters, so I tried `/<a [^>]*\bhref\s*=\s*"\K[^"]*anyurl.com[^"]{0,20}$/`, without success. Can you help me with this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide a few different sample strings to test against and your expected output for each.  If you ping me, I'll come back and post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't named what language is going to be running this pattern, but if you are using `\K` chances are you can use a positive lookahead...

Pattern ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZnYkoO/5)):

```
<a[^"]+href *= *"\K[^"]{0,20}(?=")
```

Inputs/Outputs:

```
<a href="someurl.com">                       # someurl.com
<a href="averyveryverylongurlstring.com">    #
<a href="anotherurl.com">                    # anotherurl.com
```

Comment: @vloryan What is the status of this question? Anything to fix with my answer?